# How do I add or use the MAX Function to a Date field containing DateSerial function to query most recent date?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using the DateSerial Function to convert the date on a column like this:

```
(DateSerial(CInt(Left([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],5,2)),
CInt(Right([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],2)))) AS Application_Date
```

The date comes from an Oracle linked table which is in a text datatype in Access. All is working, however, I need to add the MAX Function or find a way to get the most recent APP_DATE.

How do I add the MAX Function or what Function can I use so that if there are two APP_DATES, I get the most recent?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change depending on what you really need to accomplish. If this is the only column you need to query then you should be able to do:

```
SELECT MAX((DateSerial(CInt(Left([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],5,2)),
CInt(Right([EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE],2)))) 
AS Application_Date FROM EXAMPLE_TBL;
```

On the other hand, if you need to query multiple columns you need to try something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, MAX(DateSerial(CInt(Left([APP_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([APP_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([AP‌​P_D‌​‌​ATE],2)))) AS Application FROM tablename GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Is there a reason you are storing it as a text type rather than DateTime?

Comment: Very Interesting: Which process will you suggest or recommend? I only suggested using the MAX because it was the best or right way to go.

Comment: I was editing my answer for that very issue while you commented. See above.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I am working with an Oracle DB and the tables are locked. I can only Link to the tables, I cannot do anything else. I can make the tables local and change the data type, however, the data becomes dead, meaning the data is not updated because it becomes disconnected from the LIVE DB.

Comment: IS the Limit 1 supported in Access? I am getting an Error Message: Syntax Error in ORDER BY CLAUSE.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I've done some further poking around about Access date functions and I think the [DateValue() Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datevalue.php) function may make things cleaner for you. You should be able to do the following: `select DateValue(EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE) AS Application_Date FROM EXAMPLE_TBL where DateValue(EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE) = MAX(DateValue(EXAMPLE_TBL.APP_DATE));` (or similar with the Order By Desc Limit 1).

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot instead of Limit MS products use the TOP keyword. You want to do `SELECT TOP 1 (DateSerial...` and then finish at ORDER BY DESC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6806/discussion-between-unaverage-guy-and-ilion)

Comment: Update: The Max function approach worked perfectly! Thanks a million!